# How to partition sets A(1),…,A(N) in such a way so that elements of each partition are shared between the same number of original sets.

Tags: set-partition

For example, suppose that q(k) denotes number of elements from the original sets shared between k sets (k=1,…,N).  Our objective is to find all sets Q such each Q(k) only contains elements which belong to k original sets.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Let $B$ be the set of all the elements of all the $A$s.  Associate each element of $B$ with $k$, the number of sets it is a member of.  And then.....